# Calculating Sum of Hierarchical Query, Grouped by Type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hierarchy

I have a table TRANSFERS which contains these columns: `account_id`, `father_account_id`, `amount`, `type`.

This table represents all transfers of money made from the specific account, their amount, and what were they paying for by types (such as food/school/taxes etc).

What I need to do, is for every main account (an account without a parent) find out how much money was transfered from it (which means summing up and adding also transfers from its child accounts), grouped by the type.

For example:

```
account_id | type | amount

   1234    | food  | 500

   1234    | taxes | 750

   1111    | food  | 200

   1111    | school | 600
```

I've looked around and couldn't find a solution anywhere.
Any help would be very much appriciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your hierarchy multiple levels or only a single level?  Also, can you update your example with the father_account_id as well?

Comment: "Divided by the type" doesn't make much sense. Did you mean "grouped by the type"?

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes sorry that's what I meant (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use operator [connect_by_root](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators004.htm#i1035022) and sum values for each root id and type:

```
select root account_id, type, sum(amount) amount
  from (
    select connect_by_root(account_id) root, type, amount
      from transfers
      connect by father_account_id = prior account_id and type = prior type
      start with father_account_id is null )
  group by root, type
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3fb8/1)</sup>